# Display some li's with next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, tabnavigator

I'm creating bootstrap tabs. In each tab I have some selects with different options.
I want to place each select option in a `<li>`, and at the beginning in the active tab only 4-5 li's will be enabled.

For the remaining `<li>` I want to make a "next" button (and of course a "previous" button as well) and some transition animation.

Does anybody know how to do that in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, i know how to do next and previous buttons for tubs, but don't understand how to make this buttons for li-elements

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Could you please post your code for making next/prev buttons with tabs and perhaps we can modify it for `li`

Comment: i whan't to do that thing: in tabs can be 1,2,3 or maybe 10 selects...i want to display 5 selects, and if number of selects more than 5, i want to add next button. after click want to add some transition and display the other 5 selects..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crudetone/y6ybzjo0/